# I'm confused with using the/a/an, examples

Tags: articles

It's been always confusing for me to use articles.
I don't want to go into details, but only with general use of articles.
So, general rule, as far as I know is that we use "a/an" when we mention something for the first time. When we mention it again, we should use "the".

In this example dialogue:

> A: Is there a lot of space in your flat?
>   B: Yes, on a wall in the living room.

Why there is "in the living room" and not "in a living room"?
He mentions the living room for the first time, so why isn't used "a living room"?

Second general rule is that we use "the" when we talk about something specific. So:

Second example:

> Well, there isn't another shop around here, but there is a nice shop with paintings near my place.

Why in this example there is use "a nice shop" instead of "the nice shop"? He mentioned "shop" twice, and he even said it more specific for the second time. According to the rule, when we say something more specific, we should use "the".

Another example:

> A: Hey Fred, are there any nice paintings in this furniture shop?
>   B: Well, there are two. There is a modern painting over there and an old painting of a horse over there.

Person B says about specific paintings, why does he use "a modern painting" and "an old painting of a horse", he even points where are they using "over there". Shouldn't he use "the"?

Comment: B is not talking about any living room, but _the_ one in his flat.

Comment: Yes, but he also is not talking about any wall, but the one in his living room. So, why there is "a" wall not "the" wall?

Comment: The room has four walls. Evidently there is space on only one of them.

Comment: Ok. What about second example with the shops and third example with the paintings?

Comment: The first example doesn't make much sense. When we think of space in a flat or any home, people don't normally think how large a wall is but how many rooms a home has or how large the rooms are. What is the context of the dialogue? What was said immediately before and after?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t include all the dialogue. They are talking about paintings that they want to buy.

Comment: Well, that's kind of important to know. Please include the context IN the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A: Is there a lot of space in your flat?
>   B: Yes, on a wall in **the** living room.
>
> The OP asks: *Why there is "in the living room" and not "in a living room"? He mentions the living room for the first time, so why isn't used "a living room"?*

It is common to use the definite article when we speak about *the* rooms in our homes. For example, a couple might tell the owners of a paint shop, 
“We need to decorate *the* children's bedroom, *the* master bedroom, and *the* kitchen, too.”

> Well, there isn't another shop around **here**,

the listener understands what "here" refers to

> but there is **a nice shop** with paintings **near my place**

We can infer that the listener is  either unfamiliar with the location or with the shop, so "a (nice) shop" means **one of many shops** that are near the speaker's home. If the speaker had said

> but there is **the nice shop** with paintings near my place

it would suggest that the listener **already knows about this shop**, maybe he or she has already visited the area where the speaker lives and seen the aforementioned shop.